# Transmitting Serial data via Wi-Fi from Raspberry Pi to Wi-Fi Module

Tags: wifi, serial, arduino, uart

I previously built two separate projects for sending/receiving data between an Arduino and a Raspberry Pi 3. One transmitted via Bluetooth (HC-05 Module on the Arduino-side to the built-in BT module on the Pi) and the other transmitted via LoRa (Two RYLR896 Modules). Both of these projects were extremely similar. Each device would write data to their TX lines, transmit over their respective protocol, at which point data was received by the other unit's RX line. Very simple, worked great.

Attached here is the Raspberry Pi Script for the Bluetooth Project:

```
import serial
import time

# Connection to local BT Module (on-board)
bluetooth = serial.Serial("/dev/rfcomm0", 115200)

while True:
        # If Pi receives data, read it and print it out.
        if bluetooth.inWaiting() > 0:
                data = bluetooth.readline()

                if (data != ''):
                        decoded = data.decode('utf-8')
                        print("RECEIVED: {}".format(decoded))
                        time.sleep(1)
                        data = ''
                        bluetooth.flushInput()

        # Send back some data, or exit script
        output = input("Enter: ")
        string = '{0}'.format(output)

        if output == 'exit':
                bluetooth.close()
                exit()
        else:
                bluetooth.write(string.encode("utf-8"))
                string = ""
                output = ""
```

I would like to make another very similar project, but with Wi-Fi. In this particular case, I am using a WiFly RN-171 Module on the Arduino-side. I would like to use the Pi's built-in Wi-Fi module on the other side.

I'm unclear on at least two things:

1. How to pair the Pi to the RN-171 module. I believe I had to do with with BT, but it was nearly a year ago and I can't quite remember what that process was like.
2. How to create the instance of the connection in the script. I'm fairly certain that I would just change the 5th line to something like the following:
   `wifi = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600)`
   but I'm not really sure. I'm not even sure that the WiFi module is connected via UART. If it's not, and there's not easy way to use it for this sort of communication, I imagine that I can just use another RN-171 module, connected to the RX/TX line on the Pi-side of the project

Any advice on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Best,
Joe